# Gimp: create single colour logos from full coloured ones

Tags: gimp, logo

I would like to create images like the logos below. How do I create a single colour version of a company's logo?

For example, how would I transform [Google's logo](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Googlelogo.png) (that has many colours and gradients, etc) into one that was a single colour.

I would like to create a single colour version of logos in order to use them on a webpage similar to the way they are used on the Grails homepage:

[image: Screenshot from Grails homepage]

https://grails.org/

Comment: I downvoted your question because you have shown no effort or created a proper question.  Instead of posting a link to someone's site (which could be considered by some as posting spam) and asking how to re-generate a logo I would suggest making an [edit] to your question with effort, a picture of what you're trying to do and what exactly you're having problems with doing.

Comment: you would typically ask the company for the single color version of their logo. Many companies have different versions of their logos.

Comment: @Darth_Vader thanks for the feedback (not every down voter gives it). I hope the edited question is now more suitable.

Comment: @DA01 that's a good point. I'm not sure these companies can provide them (some are small one person companies), but it's worth a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did, was make sure to download the transparent PNG version of the logo (if a transparent version is not available, you will just have to manually select the text/shapes) and import into Gimp. I then created a new layer, and used the brush tool to make it solid red. Then I desaturated the PNG logo until it was grey scale, like this (I hid the red layer for this screenshot):

[image]

Now I used Brightness and Contrast and pumped the values all the way up to make it completely white, like so:

[image]

Now I unhid the solid red layer to make it look like this:

[image]

And the original image looked like this:

[image]

Hope this helped you!

- TrivisionZero